# Skip rows in CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
kf = 10
sets = 90
for i in range(0, kf):
    chunk[i] = pd.read_csv("Dataset.csv", skiprows=(i*sets), nrows=sets)
```

By printing i always get the 90 first rows instead of 0 to 89 and 90 to 179 etc. How can i correct the initialization in order to first skip the lines and the start reading the file ?

Output with kf = 100 and sets = 9.

```
X1        X2        X3   ...         X29       X30  Target
0 -2.335543 -2.325887 -2.367347   ...    2.001746  3.102024       1
1 -0.132771  0.463992 -0.282286   ...    3.003794  2.473191       1
2 -1.000121 -1.512276 -3.326958   ...    0.155254  5.855211       1
3 -1.170981 -3.493062 -2.241450   ...    3.228326  3.301115       1
4 -1.449553 -1.428624 -1.401973   ...    1.547833  2.008935       1
5 -1.657024 -1.567071 -1.784387   ...    0.606907 -2.135309       1
6 -0.323730 -1.237250 -2.679961   ...   -1.365039  3.101155       1
7 -1.011255 -0.706056 -1.583983   ...   -0.678562 -1.950106       1
8  0.388855  0.359412  0.037113   ...   -3.413041 -4.051897       1

[9 rows x 31 columns]
         X1        X2        X3   ...         X29       X30  Target
0 -2.335543 -2.325887 -2.367347   ...    2.001746  3.102024       1
1 -0.132771  0.463992 -0.282286   ...    3.003794  2.473191       1
2 -1.000121 -1.512276 -3.326958   ...    0.155254  5.855211       1
3 -1.170981 -3.493062 -2.241450   ...    3.228326  3.301115       1
4 -1.449553 -1.428624 -1.401973   ...    1.547833  2.008935       1
5 -1.657024 -1.567071 -1.784387   ...    0.606907 -2.135309       1
6 -0.323730 -1.237250 -2.679961   ...   -1.365039  3.101155       1
7 -1.011255 -0.706056 -1.583983   ...   -0.678562 -1.950106       1
8  0.388855  0.359412  0.037113   ...   -3.413041 -4.051897       1

[9 rows x 31 columns]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need parameter [`chunksize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk) in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
for df in pd.read_csv("Dataset.csv", chunksize=sets):
    print(df)
```

EDIT:

I create sample data with your code, problem is values of columns are incorrectly parsed, so is necessary parameter `names` with `if-else` with `None` for first group:

```
import pandas as pd

#original data
temp=u"""colA,colB
A,1
B,2
A,3
C,4
B,5
A,6
C,7
B,8
A,9
C,10
B,11
A,12
C,13
D,14
B,15
C,16"""
```

---

```
kf = 3
sets = 6

#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'Dataset.csv'
cols = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), nrows=0).columns
print (cols)
Index(['colA', 'colB'], dtype='object')

for i in range(0, kf):
    if i == 0:
        val = 0
        names = None
    else:
        val = 1
        names = cols
    df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), 
                     skiprows=(i*sets) + val, 
                     nrows=sets, 
                     names=names)
```

---

```
    print (df)

  colA  colB
0    A     1
1    B     2
2    A     3
3    C     4
4    B     5
5    A     6
  colA  colB
0    C     7
1    B     8
2    A     9
3    C    10
4    B    11
5    A    12
  colA  colB
0    C    13
1    D    14
2    B    15
3    C    16
```

Comment: Yes that works for same size of chunks. But what if i want to change the size ? Shouldn't **skip rows** work before **nrows** ?

Comment: @AndrewZacharakis -  I tested your solution and working nice, can you add some sample data for show your problem? E.g `kf = 2
sets = 6` and some `20` rows data.

Comment: I added an example and i made the chunks to be 9 rows long.

Comment: @AndrewZacharakis - there is not some overwritting data? If change `chunk[i]` to `a` and then `print (a)` it working? What is chunk ?

Comment: I added the print(a) just after reading in the for loop and still prints the first 90 rows. A chunk is part of the dataset.

Comment: What version of pandas do you use ?

Comment: @AndrewZacharakis I use `0.23.4`, but it seems problem in data

Comment: @AndrewZacharakis - added data sample with a bit changed your solution, can you check it?